# Pull out the data with keyNumber

Tags: c, struct

```
struct Store {
    int number;
    char name[50];
    double caloNumber;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int totalCalo = 0;
    int keyNumber;

    struct Store store1 = {1,"A",390},
    store2 = {2, "B",710},
    store3 = {3, "C",569},
    store4 = {4, "D",450},
    store5 = {5, "E",630},
    store6 = {6, "F",370},
    store7 = {7, "G",720},
    store8 = {8, "H",680},
    store9 = {9, "I",570},
    store10 = {10, "J",530},
    store11 = {11, "K",570},
    store12 = {12, "L",380},
    store13 = {13, "M",670},
    store14 = {14, "N",590},
    store15 = {15, "O",430};


    printf("Enter the number");

    printf("/Breakfast : \n");
    scanf("%d",keyNumber);

    printf("/Lunch : \n");

    printf("/Dinner : \n");


    //caculate 3 calories

    return 0;
}
```

I got some trouble in pulling specific data with the number which User type in.
EX: A~O is the name of store , the app will ask which store user took , and user will enter the "keyNumber" of it, and the third number is calories data. 
My question is how to get the calories data from the keyNumber. There is no map and dictionary in C language, so I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Use array instead of declaring n number of variables. Also     `scanf("%d",keyNumber);` -->`scanf("%d",&keyNumber);`

Comment: oh I forget I could use the two dimensional array , thank U @kiranBiradar !!

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d",keyNumber);`  This results in trying to use the contents of `keyNumber` (which is not initialized) as the address of where to place the scanned integer.  I.E. Not correct.  Suggest; `scanf( "%d", &keyNumber`);`  Note the '&' so the address of 'keyNumber' is passed.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {`  when the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, then to avoid two warning messages from the compiler about unused parameters, us the signature: `int main( void )`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `gperf` (https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) to statically generate a perfect hash if you really don't want to force the user to look up the number of the food, and still have lookups `O(1)`. Something like this,

```
%ignore-case
%readonly-tables
%struct-type
struct month { const char *name; int calories; };
%%
A, 390
B, 710
C, 569
D, 450
E, 630
F, 370
G, 720
H, 680
I, 570
J, 530
K, 570
L, 380
M, 670
N, 590
O, 430
%%

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const struct month *month(const char *str) {
    return in_word_set(str, strlen(str));
}

int main(void) {
    const struct month *a = month("A"), *a_lc = month("a"), *z = month("z"),
        *j = month("j");
    printf("A: %d.\n"
        "a: %d.\n"
        "z: %d.\n"
        "j: %d.\n", a ? a->calories : -1, a_lc ? a_lc->calories : -1,
            z ? z->calories : -1, j ? j->calories : -1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Then, `gperf Calories.gperf > Calories.c`. As of `gperf 3.0.4`, the `C` compiler complains that the `len` parameter is unused, but that's probably because `len == 1` for all the samples in your example. It also complains about a missing initialiser, but that's trivially fixed.

```
A: 390.
a: 390.
z: -1.
j: 530.
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not a C guy, but as a general programming logic I guess you could put store1-store15 into an array, and then iterate over the array until you find the store with given key.